# Vim disable tab-completion

Tags: vim

I recently installed vim7.3 using "`--with-features=big`", because I like almost all of those features. However, one thing that it does that I don't like is enables tab-completion: in normal mode, if you hit tab, vim "intelligently" begins omni-completion if you're near a "word".

Now, I use the [Smart Tabs plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=231), and I need my tab key to not be auto-complete. However, I like all the other "`--with-features=big`" features, and I'm loathe to go down to "`--with-features=normal`", which doesn't affect my tab key.

Does anyone know how to disable the tab-completion when compiling vim --with-features=huge?

Comment: In normal mode, <tab> jumps to the next newer entry in the jump list. This behavior is not affected by any Vim feature. In insert mode, <tab> inserts a <tab> character. If you are seeing a different behavior, it is caused by your ~/.vimrc or a plugin. To find out where <tab> is being mapped, execute `:verbose nmap <tab>`.

Comment: If you had posted that as an answer, I'd mark this question as answered. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Copied from my comment.]

In normal mode, <tab> jumps to the next newer entry in the jump list. This behavior is not affected by any Vim feature. In insert mode, <tab> inserts a <tab> character. If you are seeing a different behavior, it is caused by your ~/.vimrc or a plugin. To find out where <tab> is being mapped, execute

```
:verbose nmap <tab>
```

Answer (score 5):

you can try this command to find out what has mapped the tab-key in insert mode:

```
:verbose imap <tab>
```

and you can get the hint to handle the problem.